# Plotting running time of a function in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to plot a running time of a function by changing some variables in the function in Julia. For example:

```
for i=1:10
    @time (10^n)
end
```

How can I plot the running time for i=1,...,10?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `x=[@elapsed(10^n) for n=1:10]` then plot the array `x`

Comment: or `@belapsed` from BenchmarkTools.jl in the same setting as proposed above. I recommend you to read BenchmarkTools.jl documentation before running any benchmarking in Julia as it is a tricky topic.